# Can I use PARTITION BY with a GROUP BY clause? SQL Server 2012

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate, partition

I'm new to windowed functions.  Here is the original table with 4 types of fruit.

```
fruit   quantity
orange  100
banana  27
banana  20
orange  5
melon   5
apple   1
banana  10
banana  4
banana  36
banana  86
banana  47
apple   32
banana  7
banana  5
banana  3
```

Is it possible to turn this into the percentage each fruit makes up of the total quantity for EVERYTHING?  Here is what I want:

```
fruit       total       percentage
apple       33          9%
banana      245         63%
orange      105         27%
melon       5           1%
```

Here is the code I'm trying out, but it's giving me an error:

```
SELECT fruit
, SUM(quantity) / SUM(quantity) OVER () * 100
FROM fruit_inventory
GROUP BY fruit
```

If I undo the `GROUP BY` and remove the first `SUM(quantity)` then I get multiple records that look like this:

```
fruit   quantity    percentage
apple   1           0%
apple   32          8%
banana  27          7%
banana  20          5%
banana  10          3%
banana  4           1%
banana  36          9%
banana  86          22%
banana  47          12%
banana  7           2%
banana  5           1%
banana  3           1%
melon   5           1%
orange  100         26%
orange  5           1%
```

Comment: Add an ORDER BY fruit in your OVER clause

Comment: That still fails.  Should I remove something?

Comment: Whats the error,might try to multiply with 100 after adding some parantheses

Comment: Column 'quantity 'is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I removed the * 100 and nothing changed.

Comment: You also need something to parttion by in you over() clause like OVER(PARTITION BY Fruit ORDER BY Fruit) this site will tell you everything you need to know to solve this scroll to the very bottom: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: That gave me the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a windowed `sum` of the aggregate `sum`.

```
SELECT  Fruit ,
        SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity ,
        SUM(Quantity) / SUM(SUM(Quantity)) OVER () * 100
FROM    @fruitbasket
GROUP BY Fruit;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  I think I am starting to understand usage of OVER more.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
declare @fruitbasket table
    (
     Fruit nvarchar(50),
     Quantity decimal(19, 5)
    );

insert  into @fruitbasket
        (Fruit, Quantity)
values  (N'orange', 100),
        (N'banana', 27),
        (N'banana', 20),
        (N'orange', 5),
        (N'melon', 5),
        (N'apple', 1),
        (N'banana', 10),
        (N'banana', 4),
        (N'banana', 36),
        (N'banana', 86),
        (N'banana', 47),
        (N'apple', 32),
        (N'banana', 7),
        (N'banana', 5),
        (N'banana', 3);

select  Fruit,
        sum(Quantity) as Quantity,
        sum(Quantity) / (
                         select sum(Quantity) as Total
                         from   @fruitbasket
                        ) * 100 as PercentageOfTotal
from    @fruitbasket
group by Fruit;
```

Comment: I love this answer because I am starting to use correlated subqueries more now.

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE (Common Table Expression) you can have the results like you wanted.
Overall CTE's do have better performance and are better readable.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        Fruit
        ,SUM(Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY fruit ORDER BY fruit) AS sumProducts
        ,SUM(SUM(Quantity)) OVER ()  AS totalProducts
    FROM stackOverflow
    GROUP BY 
        Fruit
        ,Quantity
)
SELECT Fruit, CAST(sumProducts AS INT) AS sumProducts, CAST(100 * sumProducts / totalProducts AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS percentage
FROM cte
```